# Batch file to check if stated directories are empy and remove all files and documents

Tags: batch-file, delete-file

I'm looking for a batch file to clear a few directories of all files and folders, and make a report on if the directory was empty/if it was cleared.

I've looked online and tried a few suggestions, however none have worked. I can delete files but not folders, plus that doesn't use an IF statement to output if the directory was empty.

The contents of the directory will be random and have unknown files and folder names as we are using them as temporary locations that need to be deleted at the end of every day.

I have tried:
if EXIST "path\to\directory*.* " del "path\to\directory*.* "
But that doesn't delete folders.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Read both `del /?` and `rd /?`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this Resolves the issue

```
@Echo off
Echo Beginning Cleaning Process
Echo Please Have patience
if not exist C:\path\to\file\file.exe goto End
if not exist C:\path\to\folder\folder goto End
if not exist C:\path\to\another\folder goto End
DEL C:\path\to\file\file.exe
DEL C:\path\to\folder\folder 
DEL C:\path\to\another\folder
ALL Files Have Been Removed, Hopefully
pause
:End
Echo All Files Not Removed
Pause
```

If you want to remove all the Text files in the directory than you can use

`DEL C:\Path\to\Text\file\*.txt`

If you want to reomve all files in the folder then you can try this

Lets name the folder `xyz` which is in `C:\True\xyz`

```
RMDIR /S "C:\True\xyz"
MD "C:\True\xyz"
```

The `RMDIR` command will remove the directory and all the folders and files in it. Then the `MD` command will make a new directory with the same name and will obviously will be empty !

Comment: Hi,

I've got something similar now but while I can use wildcards for deleting files I can't for folders. I won't know any of the files or folder names as we are using some folders for temporary files that need to be deleted at the end of every day.

Thank you for trying however. I'll update the question for more information as I wasn't clear.

Comment: @Harvey Post is Updated